# How to switch SSL Verify off for Neo4j's RestGraphDatabase?

Tags: java, ssl, neo4j

I'm running my NEO4j HA cluster behind SSL.

I'm writing a client in Java that manages some data. Now since I'm only using SSL to encrypt communication, I'm using a self-signed cert. But now I'm facing an

```
uglycom.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException
```

Any ideas how to tell Neo4J not to verify the cert?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to generate a self-signed certificate on your own, Neo4j will do that for you when configured to do so.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_https_support

> The Neo4j server includes built in support for SSL encrypted
>   communication over HTTPS. The first time the server starts, it
>   automatically generates a self-signed SSL certificate and a private
>   key. Because the certificate is self signed, it is not safe to rely on
>   for production use, instead, you should provide your own key and
>   certificate for the server to use.

In the case that you are using the Neo4j generated self-signed cert and you're still having issues, please update your question with your configuration details in the `neo4j-server.properties` file for each of your HA instances (if they aren't the same).

Comment: It's not a server configuration issue I'm having. It's the JAVA rest client that needs some love